# Como criar um botão num Fragment para android?

Tags: android, button, fragment

Criei um botão que tem como objetivo fazer random de uma imagem. No entanto, o botão e a imagem não estão a aparecer no android. O código que estou a utilizar é o seguinte:

```
 ImageView imageView;
Random r;
Integer[] images = {
        R.drawable.img_fra,
        R.drawable.img_acai,
};

int pickedImage = 0, lastPicked = 0;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(fragment_home, container, false);
        view.findViewById(R.id.imagedizqqcoisa);
        view.findViewById(R.id.buttondizqqcoisa);

        r = new Random();

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                do {
                    pickedImage = r.nextInt(images.length);
                } while (pickedImage == lastPicked);

                lastPicked = pickedImage;
                imageView.setImageResource(images[r.nextInt(images.length)]);


                pickedImage = r.nextInt(images.length);
            }
        });
        return view;

    }

}
```

Comment: Onde estão estao os botões? Você declarou os botoes? Deveria se assim  ```Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.buttondizqqcoisa);```. E assim ```button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()```

Comment: Sim declarei os botões. Fiz como disse e mesmo assim não está a resultar.

Comment: Já me aparece a imagem e o botão mas o botão não funciona. O código está no início.

Comment: Observe que seu metodo onClick() não esta no botao mas, sim no view do frgament. Nessa parte  ```view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() ```

Comment: @BernardoLopes já consegui. Obrigado